# What will be the accuracy of an Atomic (Quantum) Inertial Sensor used in spaceflight?

Tags: spacecraft, attitude, sensors

In relation to the [question](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/26536/using-what-technology-one-can-keep-a-spacecraft-truly-non-rotating) I was looking for the perfect sensor that would help me achieve perfect non rotating spacecraft. My search made me look for exotic phenomenon that can be utilized for such endeavour. [This](https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-00106374/document) paper mentions about Atomic Inertial sensor that can use matter wave instead of laser to get high precision acceleration and rotation rate. My question is what will be the accuracy of such a device if made possible to work?

---

The technique has received more attention in the popular press recently as a *Quantum Accelerometer*.

There are videos of a developer explaining the physics involved in:

- Extremetech's [‘Quantum Accelerometer’ Tracks Location Without GPS](https://www.extremetech.com/extreme/280443-quantum-accelerometer-tracks-location-without-gps)
- Forces.net's [Could This New Quantum 'Compass' End Satellite Dependency?](https://www.forces.net/news/could-new-quantum-compass-end-satellite-dependency)

The YouTube video (below) is also linked in Imperial College London's own page about the technology: [Quantum ‘compass’ could allow navigation without relying on satellites](https://www.imperial.ac.uk/news/188973/quantum-compass-could-allow-navigation-without/)

Note that a set of three 3D accelerometers separated by a gap can be used in differential mode to measure angular acceleration as well, and so could potentially provide gyroscopic attitude determination as well as inertial translation measurement.

**But be very careful** not to confuse with "the other quantum compass" also discussed recently that uses quantum effects inside diamond as an actual magnetic compass. [1](https://www.wired.com/story/quantum-physicists-found-a-new-safer-way-to-navigate/), [2](https://futurism.com/the-byte/quantum-navigation-gps) which depends on an extremely accurate 3D map of the Earth's magnetic field and is unrelated to this technology.

Comment: Definitely, it isnt just about that. Nonetheless, it does mention it.

Comment: There's more information recently, I've added some links and text to help explain the principle involved.

Comment: Wow, you remember to even help get more links for old questions !

Comment: It's a cool question!