# Has Hubble ever focused on something close enough that it had to move away from being focused at infinity?

Tags: history, photography, record, hubble

Hubble wouldn't have to change focus for [Pranksat](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/18201/12102) to work because Pranksat is cleverly designed to present a virtual image with a focus at infinity. But if the diffraction-limited Hubble wanted to bring something much closer than the Moon into focus, at some point it would have to move away from the best focus for celestial objects.

This question was inspired by a discussion under [this answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/50864/12102).

Has this ever happened?

**Question:**

1. Has Hubble ever focused on something close enough that it had to move away from being focused at infinity?
2. If so, what's the closest distance that this has happened, *or at least would need to if it did*?

Comment: Interesting question. Naively, I would have thought that Hubble doesn't even have the capability to change its focus away from infinity!

Comment: @user2705196 I'm guessing that it will have some range of focus to accommodate manufacturing errors, thermal and other mechanical variations, etc. During the Shuttle days when they replaced instruments a few times those were not installed to microns of accuracy; there must be some range focusing to insure each instrument on the telescope can achieve best focus. I'm not sure what the full range of focus is though, and if it differs between instruments. That would determine just how close Hubble could focus.

Comment: See this question: https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/58765/how-does-the-jwst-change-focus-when-it-goes-from-looking-at-a-near-subject-to-lo

Comment: @MarkFoskey I'd already linked the two questions; is there something about Hubble that we should see at that JWST question?

Comment: Oh, I missed that you had linked it. Should have known you would have, though. My bad.

Comment: @MarkFoskey Oh no bad whatsoever! I usually use "different but related" to avoid providing close-as-duplicate-without-reading fodder.

Answer (score 6):

> 2. If so, what's the closest distance that this has happened, or at least would need to if it did?

Hubble's resolution is 0.014 arc seconds (6.8e-8 radian) and its mirror diameter is 2.4 m. So objects closer than (2.4/2)/6.8e-8 m ~= 18,000 km will become detectably blurred and would benefit from refocussing.

Comment: Considering the closest thing that Hubble has photographed I believe is the Moon, that pretty much means it hasn't had to change its focus.

Comment: @PearsonArtPhoto I know it used reflected earthshine from the Moon to study the transmission of sunlight through Earth's terminator as a test of exoplanet signatures, so the Moon served as basically a big attenuator/diffuser. Are you sure it actually focused on the surface of the Moon? This particular experiment might have worked better if it was out of focus.

Comment: @uhoh https://hubblesite.org/contents/media/images/1999/14/796-Image.html?news=true

Comment: @PearsonArtPhoto *cool!* [How often and for what reasons does Hubble use two different instruments at the same time? Is this a standard operation mode, or a "clever trick"?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/50464/7982)